# Flag summary layout broken

Tags: bug, design

[image: freehand circles ftw]

As you see on the picture, flag summary layout is broken. The right column should be on the right, instead of below the left column.

This doesn't happen on the other SE sites.

Tested on latest Chrome and Firefox.

As Vogel612 pointed out, this is caused because `.subheader` doesn't correctly clear the floats. Adding the following CSS code fixes the problem:

```
.subheader::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: I don't have the bar and it's on the left for all sites for me.

Comment: @Mast The bar is from a userscript, but it's not caused by it, because I checked it also on Firefox, where I don't have any userscripts.

Comment: The root cause for this seems to be that `.subheader` does not correctly clear the floats before `.mainbar` is getting into the page, which leads to `.sidebar` getting broken to after the mainbar. One way of fixing is to insert a `<br/>` after `.subheader`, forcing the left-float to the left border of `#content`

Comment: I was able to reproduce with Firefox and Edge as well. Looks like a CSS issue probably. Anyone else wanting to try to reproduce, just go to your profile and under the "IMPACT" table click "_N_ helpful flags"

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE, and Edge (Win10) and Firefox (Linux)

Comment: thanks for reporting, i'll take a look at this!

Comment: Related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/flagging-history-appears-at-the-bottom-of-page

Comment: Still seeing this bug. Anybody got a line to an SE developer?

Comment: @Paweł Napraw to pls.

Comment: @janos Please remove the [meta-tag:status-reproduced] tag, this likely affects how issues are tracked on the Stack Exchange side.

Comment: @Paweł any news on this?

Comment: I'll try to find some time at beginning of next week to fix it. Sory for delay guys!

Comment: @Paweł I am having the same issue, I checked in Opera and Firefox. I don't know if it is any help but in dev tools, disabling the `height: auto;` property in `#content>.subheader` fixes the issue.

Comment: Is this fixed yet? If so, can somebody mark it as [meta-tag:status-completed]? @Paweł